# Umbraco - SQL Server or SQLCE4? Performance and upgrade considerations

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-ce, umbraco

I am creating a customer site with the Umbraco CMS.

the cheapest database option is to go with SQLCE4, as the latest version supports this.

What concerns me about using SQLCE4 is the performance....

how many concurrent users before it starts to top out?

if i did need to upgrade to full SQL Server in the future would i be able to port all of my data over?

is the schema exactly the same for the sql server version and SQLCE4 version? because SQLCE does not support stored procedures or views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are worried about having an upgrade path, you could consider SQL Server Express (which is also free), and the upgrade (if you ever need it) would be as painless as shelling out some bucks. I am using SQL Express 2008 on one of my Umbraco installs, and the performance is more than fine. (Though this is not a high traffic site).

CE I beleive uses a SDF file format that is not compatible, the MDF file that expressSQL  uses is the same one that the bigger versions of SQL server use. The upgrade would be a nobrainer.

I'd say the schema is the same - umbraco has no views or stored procedures by default.

Comment: The hosting provider didnt have express so i recommended the full sql server to the client, and they went with it.  given the fact they are aiming for a substantial user base it makes sense to do it now rather than later